# Bootstrap validation symbol(correct and wrong symbol) font is missing

Tags: html, css, jqbootstrapvalidation, bootstrapvalidator

I am doing bootstrap validation using bootstrap.min.css for my website.I have done the validation,but font  missing creates hurdle for me.I have added a screenshorts .Please suggest me why font is missing?

[image]

code in bootstrap.min.css

```
.glyphicon-ok:before {
    content: "\e013"
}
.glyphicon-remove:before {
    content: "\e014"
}
```

It is coming in firebug ,please check it.
I have tried a lot,but unable to fix it.
Thank you in advance.
Any suggestion will highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of unknown in your question,

What version of `bootstrapvalidator` and `bootstrap` you are using?

Did you included `feedback icons` in JS?

```
feedbackIcons: {
    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
},
```

Are you loading the `bootstrap.css` or `bootstrap.min.css` from local server?

Are all font files exist and have correct names?

Is fonts folder path is correct?

**Possible solution.**

Mostly, This happens if font files missing or not loading correctly, folder name is wrong or font files path is wrong

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

load `bootstrap.css` from CDN Server,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css"/>
```

if font icons shown, then in local `bootstrap.css` file check the font paths and folder name is correct and font files does exist and file names are correct.

To get the correct fonts, go to the [Bootstrap homepage](http://getbootstrap.com/) and download the full .zip file. Extract the four font files from there to your fonts directory and everything should work.

Comment: Here i am loading bootstrap.min.css
If i am using <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css"/>  directly font is coming.

Comment: I accepted your answer,it helps me a lot.Otherwise i will remove that font section from validation